# Docker cloud builtin load balancing

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

When I deploy a new service with 3 containers via docker cloud I get 3 container endpoints and 1 service endpoint.

What I want to know is, how works the traffic forwarding on the service endpoint to the containers? Is there a built in load balancing or is this just a dns round robin?

The service endpoint has a different IP than the containers, so where is this forwarding service running?

Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find the answer here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/ports/#/service-and-container-dns-endpoints

It says about the service endpoint:

> This DNS endpoint (multiple A record) resolves to the IPs of the nodes where the containers are running, in a round-robin fashion.